# How to link and create embedded form in Powerapp

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-selected-items

[image]

May I know how PowerApps linking two different form by SOPNUMBER

**[Sales Order Transaction] = Parent**

contain = Edit Form - Default mode (new) and Gallery

**[Sales Order Item] = Child**

contain = Edit Form - Default mode (new)

**Problem :**

1. So far I not sure how to pass Sales Order Transaction 'SOPNUMBER' to
   Sales Order item.
2. I am using SQL method to store data. how to get current 'EDIT FORM-SOPNUMBER' field as record, so that filter with SOPNUMBER. For example, [items] = Filter(SOP10200,SOPNUMBER = DataCardValue8.Text).

Comment: what is the OnSelect currently for your Add Item button?
Is your Sales Order Item form in the same PowerApp or separate?

Comment: so far gallery is working. by sorting the data. i used" Filter(SOP10200,
SOPNUMBE = SOGALLERY.Selected.SOPNUMBE ". I try create new question .
)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72826313/powerapps-give-an-error-of-during-saving-to-sql-database