# powerapps give an error of during saving to SQL database

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

```
Patch(
    SOP10100,
    First(Filter(SOP10100,SOPNUMBE=SOGALLERY.Selected.SOPNUMBE)),
    {CUSTNAME:TextInput3.Text},{CUSTNMBR:TextInput4.Text},{SOPTYPE:Value(DataCardValue15.Text)},
    {DOCID:DataCardValue16.Text},{DOCDATE:DateValue3.SelectedDate},{BACHNUMB:DataCardValue18.Text},
    {LOCNCODE:DataCardValue7.Text},{CURNCYID:DataCardValue9.Text},{CSTPONBR:DataCardValue8.Text}
);
```

[image]

If I used collection it work fine, but when I wish to direct update current document inside database it come out this error. What does this sql error means?

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked here a while back, hope this helps:
[Error when submitting "new" form to SQL](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Error-when-submitting-quot-new-quot-form-to-SQL/td-p/394338)

Comment: After I read it, the forum suggested that use store Procedures to do update. Have any suggestion other than this? Is it must use store procedures to create / update / delete in powerapps.